# Joining Scipy sparse matrices without the slow scipy.sparse.vstack

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to calculate an array of size 1xN within a loop and stack every new array on top of the previous one. The length of the loop is 1,M and the function works similar to the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

mat = np.random.uniform(size=(1,N))
mat_sp = sp.coo_matrix(mat)

for i in range(1,M):

    mat_new = np.random.uniform(size=(1,N))
    mat_sp_new = sp.coo_matrix(mat_new)

    mat_sp = sp.vstack((mat_sp,mat_sp_new))
```

Which would result in an MxN matrix. However, performing this operation with **scipy.sparse.vstack** is very slow. Comparing with **numpy.vstack** or even just with a preallocated matrix and N = 10000:

```
In [1]: %timeit sp.vstack((mat_sp,mat_sp)) 
315 µs ± 7.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit np.vstack((mat,mat))
8.63 µs ± 87.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [3]: mat_final = np.zeros((2,10000))   

In [4]: %timeit mat_final[0]=mat; mat_final[1]=mat                               
4.03 µs ± 92.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

My problem is that sometimes I will need my final matrix to have sizes up to M = 10<sup>5</sup>  and  N = 10<sup>6</sup>  which with NumPy will give a `MemoryError`.

Is there a way of stacking sparse row vectors that isn't so very slow?

Comment: You're not supposed to stack on every iteration - you're supposed to stack once, at the end.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica then I'll need to store every row vector before the loop is finished, which would lead to MemoryError again though?

Comment: You can store them as individual sparse matrices. It might be better to create a presized DOK matrix, fill entries in that, and convert to your desired sparse matrix format at the end, though, or maintain coordinate and data lists manually and construct a sparse matrix at the end.

Comment: I'll have to look into that and get back to this. Cheers. @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: It's generally a good practice whenever dealing with large arrays to preemptively assign space. The reason for this is that arrays store items contiguously. If you keep allocating memory separately at different times, even if you have enough total space, you may not have enough contiguous space for your array.

Comment: Look at the `vstank` code.  It uses `bmat` which collects the `coo` attributes, and makes a new `coo` from those.

Comment: Those random arrays are not sparse.  `coo` won't save memory.

Comment: @Mercury, preemptively assigning space does not have any meaning when dealing with `scipy.sparse`.  A sparse matrix only stores the non-zero values.  That said, the OP isn't generating sparse arrays to start with, so attempting to save memory by using `sparse` is misguided.

Comment: @hpaulj yeah you're right

Comment: @hpaulj The code was just to give an example of what I want to do. However, it was a poor example as the arrays aren't sparse, as you say. In reality, my arrays consist of only a few hundred non-zero values in a matrix of 10^5 values.

Comment: Normal practice is to define the `coo` style input arrays for the whole matrix, not just one row at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a repetitive `stack`, as in `mat_sp = sp.vstack((mat_sp,mat_sp_new))`, is a bad idea, even when using `np.vstack`.  It's much better to collect all arrays in a list, and use the `stack` just once.  List append is much more efficient when used iteratively, and the `stacks` are designed to work with a whole list of objects, not just two at a time.  List append works in-place with object references; the array operations return a whole new array each time.

Let me illustrate:

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
```

function to make a sparse 1d array:

```
In [2]: def foo(): 
   ...:     x = np.zeros(10,int) 
   ...:     idx = np.random.randint(0,10,size=4) 
   ...:     x[idx] = idx 
   ...:     return x 
   ...:                                                                                        
In [3]: foo()                                                                                  
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9])
In [4]: foo()                                                                                  
Out[4]: array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9])
```

Simple list append:

```
In [5]: alist = []                                                                             
In [6]: for i in range(4): 
   ...:     alist.append(foo()) 
   ...:                                                                                        
In [7]: alist                                                                                  
Out[7]: 
[array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0])]
```

dense array from that:

```
In [8]: np.vstack(alist)                                                                       
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]])
```

sparse matrix from that array:

```
In [9]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(_)                                                               
In [10]: M                                                                                     
Out[10]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [11]: M                                                                                     
Out[11]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 11 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [12]: print(M)                                                                              
  (0, 2)    2
  (0, 8)    8
  (0, 9)    9
  (1, 3)    3
  (1, 5)    5
  (1, 9)    9
  (2, 1)    1
  (2, 6)    6
  (2, 7)    7
  (3, 1)    1
  (3, 8)    8
```

Alternative - make sparse matrix from each array, and join those:

```
In [13]: alist = []                                                                            
In [14]: for i in range(4): 
    ...:     alist.append(sparse.coo_matrix(foo())) 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [15]: alist                                                                                 
Out[15]: 
[<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>,
 <1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>]
In [16]: M1=sparse.vstack(alist)                                                               
In [17]: M1                                                                                    
Out[17]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

A sparse matrix (`coo` format) stores its information in 3 arrays (cf with [12]):

```
In [18]: M.data                                                                                
Out[18]: array([2, 8, 9, 3, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 1, 8])
In [19]: M.row                                                                                 
Out[19]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
In [20]: M.col                                                                                 
Out[20]: array([2, 8, 9, 3, 5, 9, 1, 6, 7, 1, 8], dtype=int32)
```

Notice how the first 3 values in those arrays correspond the nonzero elements of:

```
array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]

In [21]: m1 =sparse.coo_matrix(np.array([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9])) 
In [24]: m1.data                                                                               
Out[24]: array([2, 8, 9])
In [25]: m1.row                                                                                
Out[25]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [26]: m1.col                                                                                
Out[26]: array([2, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
```

A common way of constructing a sparse matrix is to collect the `data`, `row`, `col` arrays directly, possibly as lists, and then feed to to `coo_matrix`:

```
sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(N,M))
```

`sparse.vstack` passes the task to `sparse.bmat`.  Look at the `bmat` code to see how it collects the `data/row/col` attributes for each of inputs into composite arrays, and then creates the `coo` matrix.

Sample matrix generator:

```
In [38]: data, row, col = [], [], []                                                           
In [39]: for i in range(4): 
    ...:     idx = np.random.randint(0,10,size=4) 
    ...:     data.append(idx) 
    ...:     row.append(np.ones(len(idx),int)*i) 
    ...:     col.append(idx) 
    ...: data = np.hstack(data) 
    ...: row = np.hstack(row) 
    ...: col = np.hstack(col) 
    ...: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4,10)) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                       
In [40]: M                                                                                     
Out[40]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 16 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [41]: data                                                                                  
Out[41]: array([5, 8, 6, 2, 6, 3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 7, 0])
In [42]: row                                                                                   
Out[42]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
In [43]: M.A                                                                                   
Out[43]: 
array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]])
```